# change/transformate array code with phpstorm

Tags: php, arrays, phpstorm

I am wondering if it is possible to make phpstorm change/tranform

```
$arr[0][0][0] = 0;
$arr[0][0][1] = 1;
$arr[0][1][0] = 2;
$arr[0][1][1] = 3;
$arr[1][0][0] = 4;
```

into

```
$arr = [0 => [0 => [0 => 0,
                    1 => 1]
              1 => [0 => 2,
                    1 => 3]],
        1 => [0 => [0 => 4]]];
```

and/or the other way around.

I only found a function to switch between `array(...)` and `[...]`.
Maybe there is a plugin or something where I can execute a small script to do this?
even this I coundn't find. But maybe I am missing something.

**EDIT** Maybe it is possible by using a regex multiple times.

Comment: All code formatting rules are located at `Settings | Code Style`. If you unable to achieve desired result with existing options .. then you may only submit a ticket to the [Issue Tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) and maybe they will implement such rule in the future. **P.S.** The code examples you have provided require some special code transformation (before formatting) -- it's not possible ATM and I would not expect it to appear very soon.

Comment: I think this is a little missunderstanding (edited the title). It's this transformation I care about.

Comment: As I have already mentioned: such transformation is not possible ATM

Answer (score 0):

As @LazyOne commented it seams not to be possible.

But I found a workaround using the regex find & replace function:

1. separate the array in groups by the indexes except for the last one.

   ```
   // Group 1 (0,0)
   $arr[0][0][0] = 0;
   $arr[0][0][1] = 1;
   $arr[0][0][2] = 'test';
   // Group 2 (0,1)
   $arr[0][1][0] = 2;
   $arr[0][1][1] = 3;
   // Group 3 (1,0)
   $arr[1][0][0] = 4;
   ```
2. Start the array: For each group replace **the first** matching `(\$.+)\[(.+)\]\s*=\s*([\s\S]+?);` by `$1 = [$2 => $3];`. You get

   ```
   // Group 1 (0,0)
   $arr[0][0] = [0 => 0];       // <- Array started
   $arr[0][0][1] = 1;
   $arr[0][0][2] = 'test';
   // Group 2 (0,1)
   $arr[0][1] = [0 => 2];       // <- Array started
   $arr[0][1][1] = 3;
   // Group 3 (1,0)
   $arr[1][0] = [0 => 4];       // <- Array started
   ```
3. Append to Array: replace **all** matching
   `(\$.+)\s*=\s*\[([\s\S]*?)\];\s*\1\[(.+?)\]\s*=\s*([\s\S]+?);`
   by `$1 = [$2,\n$3 => $4];`.
   By this way you get

   ```
   // Group 1 (0,0)
   $arr[0][0] = [0 => 0,
   1 => 1];                    // <- Index appended
   $arr[0][0][2] = 'test';
   // Group 2 (0,1)
   $arr[0][1] = [0 => 2,
   1 => 3];                    // <- Index appended
   // Group 3 (1,0)
   $arr[1][0] = [0 => 4];
   ```
4. Repeat step 3 until there are no matches left.

   ```
   // Group 1 (0,0)
   $arr[0][0] = [0 => 0,
   1 => 1,
   2 => 'test'];               // <- Index appended
   // Group 2 (0,1)
   $arr[0][1] = [0 => 2,
   1 => 3];
   // Group 3 (1,0)
   $arr[1][0] = [0 => 4];
   ```
5. Repeat steps 1 to 4 until you have the result (you have to do the indention yourself or let phpstorm do this for you by reformatting the code)

   ```
   $arr = [0 => [0 => [0 => 0,
                       1 => 1,
                       2 => 'test'],
                 1 => [0 => 2,
                       1 => 3]],
           1 => [0 => [0 => 4]]];
   ```

This is only practical if you have to transformate a very big array.

*Notice*: The comments in the example have to be removed.

**Fun Fact** This works also in other editors or IDE's that support regex find & replace.